# React Native Realm filter item in list of type strings property

Tags: react-native, filter, realm

I have the following schemas/models, and I want to query where Employee->specialization is contains "java".

Here's my schema:

```
export class Employee {
}
Employee.schema = {
    name: 'Employee',
    primaryKey: 'employeeId'
    properties: {
        'employeeId':'string'
        'name': 'string',
        'age': 'string',
        'specialization': { type: 'string?[]' },
    }
};
```

I tried with the following but no success

```
let specialization = "java"
realm.objects('Employee').filtered("specialization CONTAINS $0", specialization)
```